# Information Disclosue issue in Wildfly and Apache Web Server

Tags: security, wildfly, disclosure

We are working in an environment where UI Requests flow to a WildFly Server (where the WAR is deployed) versioned 10.1.0 via an Apache Web Server versioned 2.4

We were running Security tests and when using a VirtualDirContext, it was possible to bypass the security constraints and view the source code of JSPs for resources served by the VirtualDirContext using a specially crafted request via Burp.

How we reproduce the vulnerability in Burp:

1. We capture a random Request via the UI and replicate it in Burp.
2. We turn the Request into a GET Request, mention the path of a JSP file and add %2520 to it.

This issue is reproducible even if the Requests go directly to the WildFly Server instead of via the Apache Web Server.

Is there a way to prevent this vulnerability? We believe validating each Request for the presence of %2520 in it in the Filter layer may not be a comprehensive fix.

**In simple words**, when we use a URL that contains the path of a JSP file present in the code, appended with %2520, the content of the JSP was disclosed. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming-related question as described in [help/on-topic]. You'll be able to find security related sites in the stackexchange network, where this would be on topic. You might also want to read on [responsible disclosure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_vulnerability_disclosure)

Comment: I understand. I have posted this query in the Security portal of the StackExchange network as well now (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/260421/information-disclosure-issue-in-wildfly-and-apache-web-server). In case someone wants to reply here, they can since I shall be checking in for it here as well